# Setuid on rcp not working as expected

Tags: linux

While pentesting in a lab, came across an rcp binary with setuid bit which looked like a potential privilege escalation vector.

```
bash-3.1$ ls -l /usr/bin/rcp
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 18544 May 18  2007 /usr/bin/rcp
```

Following the explanation at https://securiteam.com/exploits/6b00l1p0bc/ , I tried the following:

```
bash-3.1$ /usr/bin/rcp 'bob bobalina;/usr/bin/id;' 127.0.0.1
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
bash: 127.0.0.1: command not found
```

My understanding is that since rcp is setuid as root, any command executed by it must be run as root. Why am I then seeing the output of /usr/bin/id as apache, which is the user I am running as?

I'm not a great Linux guy so if I'm missing something obvious, please let me know.

I've also tried the command injection with backticks, got the same result:

```
bash-3.1$ /usr/bin/rcp ``bob bobalina;/usr/bin/id;`` 127.0.0.1
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache) bash: 127.0.0.1:
command not found
```

Comment: If you look at the example in the blog, the results of the `id` command appear to be run as the current user, not root. Have you tried their actual PoC later in the post? I'm thinking that the behavior of `rcp` is different than expected; perhaps effective UID is not root but saved UID is. Also, the backticks won't do anything, since that just runs the commands in a subshell in your current shell without even passing to `rcp`.

Comment: There is no gcc on the target machine so I modified the PoC to run other commands such as "cat /etc/shadow" but it still fails with "permission denied" error. Regardless of the PoC, shouldn't something like "rcp /etc/shadow /tmp/shadow" work since rcp is attempting to access shadow file as root? I get permission denied error still.